# Ubuntu 12.10 not booting on Lenovo Z580 with Windows 7

Tags: boot

I have Windows 7 x64 installed but after installing Ubuntu 12.10, it asks me to restart but the GRUB loader doesnt even show up, directly boots into Windows
What can i do for that ??

Comment: Probably you did not install Grub correctly. Maybe you have chosen the wrong disk where to install Grub.

Comment: so where should i exact;y install the grub, i used to do in the same way earlier, it worked

Comment: See my answer below. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a site to download a boot repair disc like this http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/
burn it and then start the system. It will repair your boot.
    Otherwise press the F12 when windows starts and see If Ubuntu is on boot devises.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot a liveDVD or liveUSB
2. Check where Ubuntu is installed. If your Ubuntu partition is on say `sda4` then you should install grub on `sda` without the last digit.
3. Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) an type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` changing sda accordingly.

More detailed information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2).

Answer (score 0):

try creating ubuntu boot disc/pendrive with SecureBoot

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but could you please provide step by step instructions for anyone who is unclear about what you're talking about?